# Rinkeby testnet with Opensea metadata not showing

Tags: rinkeby, opensea

I deployed en ERC721 smart contract to Rinkeby testnet, where I was able to see the collection i minted for myself in the constructor (with images + metadata).

Now, when I minted from a different address, I see 2 issues:

1. I cannot see the image + metadata even after refresh..
2. I cannot send (and also none of my collections from contract owner mints) my assets in MetaMask extension.

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: How are watching the image and metadata? Can you try another wallet?

Comment: Did you try to validate your metadata through Opensea API? Try visiting the following address:
https://testnets-api.opensea.io/asset/0x{contract address}/{token id}/validate/

Answer (score 3):

I was having a problem with my metadata and this article really helped.

https://docs.opensea.io/docs/4-debugging-your-metadata

It includes an api endpoint for the testnet
that will show you your token-uri and if you click that it will take you to the page that is serving your json[image]

Comment: Mine was valid, but wasn't visible till I clicked refresh button (Refresh metadata)

Comment: @gneric thank you, I just click to refresh button and my NFT showing up on opensea